# Python Pandas apply function on data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

i made a function for replace the yes value into o and the no into 1, when I applied the function on the data frame using a single column, it worked perfectly but when I tried more than column an error accrued

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgDV7.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4OtU.png]

Comment: Pandas' dataframe apply (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) is not the same as the Series' apply (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)

Answer (score 0):

What I think is the function you have defined takes only one argument but in the second case, there are 2 parameters sent to the function like[yes,no].Try applying a bitwise operator to convert it into one yes/no.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).